# Is it possible to decorate ASP.NET WEB API controller method with more than one Http attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I wonder if it's possible to decorate a WEB API controller method with more than one Http attribute as illustrated below and if possible is this the correct way to express that behaviour?
For example:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage EditRegistration([FromUri] string id, [FromBody] Registration registration)
```

I tried this and the pipeline resolves the request correctly in both cases (PUT and POST request) but I wonder if this is because of the Http attributes or because WEB API uses some other way of mapping the request to the controller method.

Comment: Remove one of the attributes and see what happens?

Comment: Good point! I just tried that, removing the PUT attribute and my PUT test failed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is more elegant way to express that:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Put)]
```